# ‘any way’ vs ‘in any way’ – When Do I Use Which?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference

my gut tells me i need to say ‘in any way’ in ‘associative means you can parenthesise terms *in any way*’, but why? what about the following sentences? what exactly are the rules?

## any way

> Michael, You must know by now that research can be slanted **any way** to make a point.
> [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/2006/0918/028a.html)

> They are outliers blessed with a freakish talent that can be expressed **any way** – devastating in a single over or a day and a half of batting.
> [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/sport/cricket-the-old-batsman-blog/2013/sep/05/batsmen-not-know-how-bat)

> The Unibox, a tall, square van enclosed in transparent panels, can be used "**any way** you please," Honda said, "as a cafe, for example, or even as a listening room".
> [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/10/26/automobiles/tokyo-show-is-smaller-and-subdued-but-still-outlandish.html)

> Seafood dishes, such as trout, salmon and sole, can be prepared "**any way** you like it".
> [HuffPo](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/stage-door-ia-free-man-of_b_798876)

## in any way

> But it doesn't hang together **in any way** that matters.
> [New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2002/11/25/obsessions)

> Because Christianity can be interpreted **in any way** you like.
> [Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/comment/charlie-hebdo-how-exactly-would-we-like-muslims-to-condemn-these-attacks-9966176.html)

> And, as we all know, data can be interpreted **in any way**.
> [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/10/28/arts/artsspecial/arts-emotional-tug-is-best-experienced-alone-a-study-finds.html)

> It's just a really fun way for girls to feel like they can be sexy **in any way** that they want to be.
> [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/music/musicblog/2014/may/09/beastie-boys-girls-feminist-sizzy-rocket-feminism-reworked)

Answer (score -2):

When you need to choose in such cases , a good rule of thumb is to pick whichever word **sounds better**."any way" is  vague , while "in any way" is  specific to the action described by the verb.Generally adding "in" in a phrase points to something specific since "in" describes something with a inner structure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That works for an experienced language user who's built up an intuition, but not for a learner if they haven't yet.

Comment: does ‘associative means you can parenthesise terms in any way’ sound better with or without ‘in’, and why might that be?

Comment: -1 On this site, we expect answers that could be verified by reference to authoritative sources. "Whichever word sounds better" cannot be attributed to an authoritative source. Also, the OP asked for rules, and your answer doesn't include any.

Comment: You stopped reading at "sounds better".